# Django: detect whether checkbox is submitted or disabled

Tags: django, checkbox, django-forms, disabled-input

In django, I have code to disable a checkbox dynamically, as unchecking it triggers some object deletion. If my object should not be deleted, the checkbox is rendered with disabled, and is not submitted.

However, in the view, I cannot distinguish between the checkbox being submitted as false and the checkbox not being submitted, as the form.cleaned_data still contains the key "is_user".

forms.py

```
if somecondition:
    self.fields["is_user"].widget.attrs['disabled'] = True
```

views.py

```
if "is_user" in form.cleaned_data:
    if form.cleaned_data["is_user"] == False:
        do dangerous deleting
        return redirect(page)
    elif form.cleaned_data["is_user"] == True:
        process information
        return redirect(page)
else:
    return redirect(page)
```

I submit the form from its checkbox-disabled state, and in the pdb shell I can type:

```
(pdb) form.cleaned_data
{'is_user': False}
```

I had expected form.cleaned_data not to contain a key for the non-submitted field. How can I detect whether it is not submitted, as opposed to submitted unchecked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference in HTML between a checkbox that is unchecked and one that is not submitted. Simply put, if you uncheck a checkbox, it is not included in the POST. This has nothing to do with Django, but is just how browsers work.

If you really need to distinguish between these states, you'll need a different control: perhaps a set of radio buttons for `is_user` with `true` and `false` values. Alternatively, if you absolutely have to have a checkbox, perhaps you could use some Javascript to set a hidden control when it is unchecked.

In any case, having code that deletes *unless* a checkbox is ticked is very definitely the wrong way to go about it. Actions should always default to the least destructive: doing something like deleting requires a positive action.

Comment: Firstly, you're right about the intent of the code, and I have changed things to respond to the status of the first model's boolean field, rather than the presence of the related object in the second model. So thank you for that nudge. On the issue of submitted data, are you saying that the form's cleaned_data will contain a key but no value for the disabled checkbox?

Comment: No: the `cleaned_data` will contain `False` for the checkbox's key, whether it is disabled or unchecked.